# the combination of ajax and tweenmax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, gsap

http://lifeto.dothome.co.kr/xe/page_FIsv96

In the page above, I called ajax.load with the following code:

```
jQuery(".open_list").on("click", function (e) {
 e.preventDefault()
 jQuery(".ajax_list").fadeOut(function () {
  var $item = jQuery(this)
  $item.load ("http://lifeto.dothome.co.kr/xe/free", function () {
   $item.fadeIn ()
  })
 })
})
```

...and inside of the loaded document (http://lifeto.dothome.co.kr/xe/free), it contains an element with a class named `open_contents`. When i click it, it opens a new div.

```
jQuery('.open_contents').click(function() {
 TweenMax.to (".board_contents", 0.5, {opacity: 1, top: 200,  ease: Bounce.easeOut})
})
```

There are two problems :

1. When I click on the title (the number 1, 2, 3), which has an `open_contents` class, it won't initiate the Greensock code to slide down from the top.
   (I only assume it is because the loaded Ajax cannot interact with the parent window...)
2. The div named `list` somehow wont close even after I click on the 'close' button, so I am not able to open the .list again.

Can anyone advise me of the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery('.open_contents').click(function() {`

When you run this code, you create an event listener for all the elements in the document *at the time*. You need to run this either after the elements are loaded (in `$item.load ("http://lifeto.dothome.co.kr/xe/free", function () {...})`), or use (I think):

`jQuery(document.body).on('click', '.open_contents', function () {`

This will run whenever any present or future element with the `.open_contents` class existing in the body is clicked.